# Javascript and style optimisation

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm working on a web application right now and it is very slow. After looking at the network monitor in Chrome, I saw that it loaded dozens of styles and scripts (possibly over 150). This is ridiculous, so I coded a PHP class to minify my scripts and styles and to cache them. It's working right now and the speed is much better!

I was just wondering, what is the best way to serve the minified JS? Is it better to print all the JS between `<script>` tags (and css between `<style>` tags) or I should put everything in a file, say js_loader.php in which I would print it and set the headers to be javascript?

What is the fastest for both the end user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can serve them minified and merged into a single file, do it.
More script/link tags means more HTTP requests and thus slower loading. Specially when it's about JS.

Read the topics in `Web Performance Best Practices and Rules` @ http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Specially the topics `#1 Minimize HTTP Requests`, `#5 Gzip Components` and `#11 Minify JavaScript and CSS`.
As for more awesomeness in load times, read `#6 Put StyleSheets at the Top` and `#7 Put Scripts at the Bottom`.

From the #7:

> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. **While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.**

Comment: If your site is running under Apache and you have access to the server configuration, you might want to look into mod_pagespeed 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod it will automate applying several best practices as suggested by Raphael

Comment: Nice one Carl. As another resource addition for sam_1421, get the .htaccess file of [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) and read it. There have lots of interest stuff (with explanation) about better serving files, regarding ETag, caching, mime-type and other you can apply on your own .htaccess (if you running you website in Apache, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the current best practies are

- Load `<style>` early in `<head>` so that it get applies early and the user does not see "half-baked" page
- Load `<script>` before `<body>` closes

See HTML5 boilerplate for example

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html

Never use inline Javascript or CSS as this increases the size of subsequent page loads (the same code gets loaded again and again...)